# My Stock gets deducted with empty cart if redirected to third party like paypal if order is not even completed

Tags: php, magento, paypal

The Problem i am facing is whenever  I place order lets suppose payment method is PayPal I am redirected to PayPal website . When i press back from browser my stock gets deducted and i cant see order in My Account also my Cart goes empty . At admin side order is listed as Pending Payment I have to cancel that in order to restore my payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its magento's basic functionality in order to convert such customers into potential ordering ones though calling or emailing.

Below listed plugin would help you :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-pending-orders-automatic-cancelation-with-stockreleaser-by-soon.html

Comment: How to maintain cart if order doesnot completes ?

Comment: I dont understand how this plugin works i have attached cron job but how to set that lead times manager there is no good documentation for it

Answer (score 1):

Try PayPal Express instead. The order only will get created in Magento once paid in PayPal. Very easy to implement and saves a big headache of trying to deal with all the side effects of the PayPal Standard setup.